# Draw curved arrows between nodes in tikz-qtree

Tags: arrows, tikz-trees, linguistics, curve-fitting

Is there a "clever" way to draw curved lines between nodes without them to go all through the picture?

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{philex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contraintes sur le mouvement}

\lb{}{La fille que j'aidais aime ce que tu détestes.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}% to allow linebreaks

\Tree 
[.TP
[.DP 
    [.DP \edge[roof]; {La fille} ]
    [.\node(aidais){CP};  \edge[roof]; {que j'\fbox{aidais}} ] ]
[.T$'$  
[.\node(temps) {V\\\Huge\color{blue}?};  ]
[.VP 
[.DP \edge[roof]; {\sout{La fille...}} ] 
[.V$'$ 
%[.V \fbox{aime} ]
[.V \node(aime){\fbox{aime}}; ]
[.\node(détestes) {CP};  \edge[roof]; {ce que tu \fbox{détestes}} ] ] ] ] ]

\node (aidais2) [below=.7cm of aidais] {};
\node (aidais3) [right=.2cm of aidais2] {};
\node (temps2) [below=.3cm of temps] {};
\node (détestes2) [below=.7cm of détestes] {};
\node (détestes3) [right=.3cm of détestes2] {};

%\draw[semithick,->] (aidais3)..controls +( west:1) and +(east:1)..(temps2);
%\draw[semithick,->] (aime)..controls +( west:1) and +(east:1)..(temps2);
%\draw[semithick,->] (détestes3)..controls +( west:4) and +(east:4)..(temps2);
\draw[-latex] (aidais3.south) -- (temps.south west);
\draw[-latex] (aime.south) -- (temps.south east);
\draw[-latex] (détestes3.south) -- (temps.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result :
[image]

My question is : **What code could draw the arrows to go 'around' the trees--not through it-- in order to reach the interrogation dot without them to cross each other ?**

I've tried many different codes, but I don't really understand what I do, I change the options randomly to discover what they do, but I can't find a way do to it.

This is an example amoung many others, and I'm always embarrassed with these arrows. So I'm looking for a solution that could be generalized to similar examples (arrows on trees). And I don't even know where to look for in the tikz documentation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also see [TiKZ make lines connecting nodes have the same endpoints](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37047) which is effectively a duplicate.

Comment: Just a comment on your code: you might want to add a `\strut` inside your `\fbox`es so that they all are the same size (and possibly reduce the `\fboxsep` to `.5pt`. (Also your example lacks the relevant `inputenc`/`fontenc` combination to display the accented characters, although I assume this is just an oversight in the MWE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are probably a lot of different ways to address this, but I find the following quite effective:

```
\draw[-latex] (aidais3.south) to[out=270,in=225,looseness=2] (temps.265);
\draw[-latex] (aime.south) to[out=270,in=270,looseness=2] (temps.280);
\draw[-latex] (détestes3.south) to[out=270,in=260,looseness=2] (temps.south);
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that I have specified the `in` angle and the `out` angle of the arrows. Note that I have also tweaked the final destination by using an angle of your `temps` node, as noted in [Add more anchors to standard TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14769/add-more-anchors-to-standard-tikz-nodes). You can tweak the `looseness` parameter as you see fit `:)`

Here's the complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{philex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contraintes sur le mouvement}

\lb{}{La fille que j'aidais aime ce que tu détestes.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}% to allow linebreaks

\Tree 
[.TP
[.DP 
    [.DP \edge[roof]; {La fille} ]
    [.\node(aidais){CP};  \edge[roof]; {que j'\fbox{aidais}} ] ]
[.T$'$  
[.\node(temps) {V\\\Huge\color{blue}?};  ]
[.VP 
[.DP \edge[roof]; {\sout{La fille...}} ] 
[.V$'$ 
%[.V \fbox{aime} ]
[.V \node(aime){\fbox{aime}}; ]
[.\node(détestes) {CP};  \edge[roof]; {ce que tu \fbox{détestes}} ] ] ] ] ]

\node (aidais2) [below=.7cm of aidais] {};
\node (aidais3) [right=.2cm of aidais2] {};
\node (temps2) [below=.3cm of temps] {};
\node (détestes2) [below=.7cm of détestes] {};
\node (détestes3) [right=.3cm of détestes2] {};

%\draw[semithick,->] (aidais3)..controls +( west:1) and +(east:1)..(temps2);
%\draw[semithick,->] (aime)..controls +( west:1) and +(east:1)..(temps2);
%\draw[semithick,->] (détestes3)..controls +( west:4) and +(east:4)..(temps2);
\draw[-latex] (aidais3.south) to[out=270,in=225,looseness=2] (temps.265);
\draw[-latex] (aime.south) to[out=270,in=270,looseness=2] (temps.280);
\draw[-latex] (détestes3.south) to[out=270,in=260,looseness=2] (temps.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```